# decode os.urandom() bytes object

Tags: python, string, hex, ascii, decode

Im trying to get a *private_key* so, I tried this:

```
private_key = os.urandom(32).encode('hex')
```

But it throws this error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

So I check questions and solved that, in Python3x bytes can be only **decode.** Then I change it to:

```
private_key = os.urandom(32).decode('hex')
```

But now it throws this error:

```
LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

And I really didnt understand why. When I tried this after last error;

```
private_key = os.urandom(32).codecs.decode('hex')
```

It says

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'codecs'

So I stuck, what can I do for fixing this? I heard this is working in Python 2x, but I need to use it in 3x.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify). It works both in Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32))
b'daae7948824525c1b8b59f9d5a75e9c0404e46259c7b1e17a4654a7e73c91b87'
```

If you need a string object instead of a bytes object in Python 3.x, use `decode()`:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()
'daae7948824525c1b8b59f9d5a75e9c0404e46259c7b1e17a4654a7e73c91b87'
```

Comment: _private_key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode('hex')
LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs_

Comment: @tamamdir, Remove `.decode('hex')` part. Just `binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32))` or `binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()`

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, `bytes` object has no `.encode()` method (to strengthen Unicode text vs. binary data (bytes) distinction).

For bytes to bytes conversions, you could [use `codecs.encode()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode):

```
import codecs
import os

print(codecs.encode(os.urandom(32), 'hex').decode())
```

And in reverse:

```
print(codecs.decode(hex_text, 'hex')) # print representation of bytes object
```

Note: there is no `.decode()` call because bytes returned by `os.urandom` has no character encoding (it is not a text, it is just a random sequence of bytes).

`codecs` may use `binascii.hexlify`, `binascii.unhexlify` internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
private_key = "".join(["%02x" % ord(x) for x in os.urandom(32)])
```

Comment: This produces the error: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found.

Comment: Mr. Me so remove ord(), leave just x. 
I've only 2.7 on BSD and Linux in my order, maybe on other platform urandom() work differently