# urandom in django model / mySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, django, cryptography

I am trying to store a urandom value into the mySQL Database of my Django project. The value must be totally random for cryptography purposes.

I am trying for hours and I am really frustrated. I googled some answers but the solutions wont work.

If I try this as here suggested [Store os.urandom variable to Sqlite database in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178657/store-os-urandom-variable-to-sqlite-database-in-django)

```
def createkey():
    random_bytes = urandom(16)
    return b64encode(random_bytes)

key = models.BinaryField(max_length=16, default=createkey)
```

... i get this error message

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'key'")
```

I also tried it with the binascii library
[os.urandom() decoding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681823/os-urandom-decoding-issue?rq=1)
like this

```
def createkey():
    return binascii.hexlify(urandom(16)).decode()
```

With that above i get this error message:

```
string argument without an encoding
```

I am using Python 3.6, Django 1.11.5 and a MySQL Database.

Is there any way to store the value of urandom into a Django Model? I would like to store it in a CharField but I am also glad if it works with other Fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to do something like this:

```
_key = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

Drop the `max_length=16` because this does not match up with `urandom(16)` ... the urandom argument corresponds to the max number of bytes.

Then, within the createkey method called on your `Model`...you want **save** a value to the database, and not simply just return a value. The return value is only accessible when called on the `Modal` instance.... e.g., `Modal.createkey()`.

So, you'll want something more like:

```
def createkey():
    self._key = binascii.hexlify(urandom(16)).decode()
```

And call your `createkey()` method on the view level.

This should resolve your `invalid default value for key` error.

Without actually replicating what you have, I have a small suspicion that you may even be able to do the following:

```
def createkey():
    random_bytes = urandom(16)
    return b64encode(random_bytes)

key = models.BinaryField(blank=True, default=self.createkey)
```

You may even get away with a `CharField`:

```
key = models.CharField(max_length = x)
```

Where `x` above is BLOCK_SIZE * 2 to hold hex data, or 4 * ( BLOCK_SIZE / 3) for base64 data. BLOCK_SIZE is 16 for your specific example.